# How can I fix sloshing while running?

Tags: running, hydration, cramps

I have a fairly persistent problem with "sloshing" sounds when running. Specifically, on the downbeat of each step, I get this feeling and sound like there's fluid being dropped suddenly. It's annoying, and eventually starts to interfere with my running since my stomach starts cramping and I start feeling like I need to find a bathroom (although, in actuality, there often is nothing to discharge). Poking around on the internet, the general consensus is that it's a factor of too much fluid in the stomach, and the way to solve it is to drink less when running. However, a) that doesn't do much good if it starts after I've been running for several minutes and b) it doesn't feel like it's at stomach level, but lower down on the body and more toward the back. It doesn't always happen, although I've found that it's a bit more common at times when I'm having one of my days-long borborygmus incidents (and yes, I've seen a doctor on that, and they basically shrugged and said it didn't seem harmful).

Keeping my core tensed seems to help, oddly enough, but that's tiring to do for several minutes at a time. Other than trying to drink less fluids during the day (I'll often down a fair amount during the day, although I try to avoid drinking too close to running for fear of cramps), is there anything I can do?

Comment: I'm assuming you run for an aerobic component.  Have you tried other types of aerobics, and, do you get the same "sloshing"?

Comment: Running is the only place I've experienced it. Given the mechanics of where it happens, I'd half expect jumproping to provoke the same symptoms, but since it's intermittent, it's kind of hard to test.

Comment: Maybe it's time to monitor what you eat before a run.

Comment: This is exactly what I get and it used to be an hoc but now as soon as I run and every single time. Did you get any resolution? I've tried avoiding certain foods, avoiding fluid, running on an empty stomach first thing when i wake up but no joy. Tried buscopan, imodium, mebeverine but nothing.

Comment: @RunnersTrots: 
No, I did not really find an answer. The cramping has gone away, but I still get a lot of sloshing and gurgling from running. These days, I just accept it as annoying noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up on this, I largely seem to have eliminated this issue through no practice other than more practice running. After doing a fairly consistent half hour of jogging 4-5 days a week for a year (side effect of me trying to squeeze in the arbitrary 10,000 step goal despite working from home eliminating most of my walking during the day), the problem basically just went away. My assumption is that something in my core stabilization or gait improved, but I have no definite answer there.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the following:

- When hydrating, do so in small amounts over long period of time rather than drinking a whole glass/cup/bottle at once
- Eat meals 3-4 hours or more before running
- Experiment with what you're eating
- Try eating something like bread before you run (not a lot, see point 2)

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had exactly the same problem and I have tried many ways of stopping it and eventually found that it happens when I’ve eaten/drunk stuff containing artificial sweeteners (especially aspartame) previously that day. The best way to stop it is to try and reduce/cut out artificial sweeteners from your diet. For me at least, it seems that over/under hydration isn’t the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same problem as well, recently I've started eating around three hours before I run which has helped a lot. I've been having a bagel and eggs and cheese for lunch every day I run, and I have felt a lot better as far as the sloshing sound goes. Also, be sure to be drinking a lot of water from when you wake up, to about an hour before the run.